# FBAnnotationClustering remove annotation in swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I am using `FBAnnotationClustering` cocoa pod library in my application to do the clustering. In this `removeAllAnnotation` method is only available in Objective-C but not in swift 3. So I am posting the swift version to help others like me. Please see my own answer below.

Answer (score 1):

**FBClusteringManager.swift:**

```
open func removeAnnotations() {
    if tree == nil {
        return
    }
    lock.lock()
    for annotation: MKAnnotation in allAnnotations() {
        tree!.remove(annotation)
    }
    lock.unlock()
}
```

**FBQuadTree.swift**

```
func remove(_ annotation: MKAnnotation) -> Bool {
    return self.remove(annotation, from: rootNode!)
}

func remove(_ annotation: MKAnnotation, from node: FBQuadTreeNode) -> Bool {

    if !FBQuadTreeNode.FBBoundingBoxContainsCoordinate(node.boundingBox!, coordinate: annotation.coordinate) {
        return false
    }

    do {
        if let index = node.annotations.index(where: {self.equate(lhs: $0, rhs: annotation)}) {
            node.annotations.remove(at: index)
            node.count -= 1
        }
    } catch {
        return false
    }

    if let northEast = node.northEast {
        if self.remove(annotation, from: northEast) {
            return true
        }
    }

    if let northWest = node.northWest {
        if self.remove(annotation, from: northWest) {
            return true
        }
    }

    if let southEast = node.southEast {
        if self.remove(annotation, from: southEast) {
            return true
        }
    }

    if let southWest = node.southWest {
        if self.remove(annotation, from: southWest) {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}

func equate(lhs: MKAnnotation, rhs: MKAnnotation) -> Bool{
    return lhs.coordinate.latitude == rhs.coordinate.latitude
        && lhs.coordinate.longitude == rhs.coordinate.longitude

}
```

Comment: could u .zip whole lib ?